# Property of Set Function related to Supermodularity

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Have set functions with the following property been studied? If so, what is the name of the property?

Let $\Omega$ be a set of elements, and let $f:\mathcal P(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a set function.

For any set $S \subseteq \Omega$ and for elements $x \in S$, $y \in \Omega \backslash S$,

$$
f(S\cup\{y\}) - f(S) \geq f(S)-f(S\backslash\{x\})
$$

Intuitively, it is similar to supermodularity, but the "increasing returns" is tied to a growing ground set rather than to an individual item.

Comment: I think you mean $f:\mathcal P(\Omega)\to \mathbb R$, as well as $y\in\Omega\setminus S$, since otherwise this definition does not make much sense

Comment: @Vsotvep thanks for the correction and clarification. Edit made.

Comment: Where do these functions arise?

Comment: @broncoAbierto Quite possibly nowhere. They arose for me out of an accidental mis-application of the definition of supermodularity, and they look like they may have some interesting implications in a stochastic optimization problem I'm working on.